# Lazyload external JS/CSS files based on controller namespace convention?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, templating, angularjs

Does angularJS have anything in place to lazyload external JS/CSS files based on ng-controller namespaces?  So that the following would append com.myApp.SomeClass.js and com.myApp.SomeClass.css to the document head?

```
<div ng-controller="com.myApp.SomeClass"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not yet, but it is in the works post v1.0.

Is your app so big that you need it? We have some impressively big apps, and have not run into this need yet, since the controllers are much more dense then when writing the same behavior without angular.

Answer (score 0):

how about using slowscript? It's really easy to lazyload on angularjs

Example:
https://github.com/flrngel/slowscript-angular-require-lazyload

Slowscript:
https://github.com/flrngel/slowscript

### core code from website

#### app.js

```
app = angular.module("mainApp", ["ui.router"]).run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(){
        slowscript.execute();
    });
});

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("sexy", {
        url: "/sexy",
        views: {
            "contents": {
                templateUrl: "/views/test.html",
                controller: "Sexy",
                reloadOnSearch: true
            }
        }
    });
});

app.controller("Sexy", function($scope) {
    slowscript.queue(function(){
        slowscript.$global.sexy($scope);
    });
});
```

#### test.html (angular view template)

```
<div ng-controller="Sexy">
    <input list="univ">
        <datalist id="univ">
            <option ng-repeat="univ in univs" value="{{univ.name}}"></option>
        </datalist>
    </input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
    <noscript src="test.js" type="text/slowscript"></noscript>
</div>
```

#### test.js

```
require(['angular','slowscript'],function(angular,slowscript){
    slowscript.$global.sexy=(function($scope){
        console.log("tada~");
        $scope.univs = [{"idx": 1,"name": "asdf"}, {"idx": 2,"name": "bsdf"}];
        $scope.$apply();
    });
    slowscript.queue_execute();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**It not possible with stock AngularJS 1.x**

> However, you can use [$oclazyload](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) to defer the loading of code files (js, HTML, CSS)

`$ocLazyLoad` works perfectly with routers like [UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/). It returns a promise and uses `resolve` property to make sure that files are loaded before the view is resolved.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad'])
     .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
      $stateProvider
          .state('stateA', {
              url: '/stateA',
              controller: 'StateACtrl',
              templateUrl: 'stateA.html',
              resolve: {
                  load: [ '$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                          return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                              {
                                  name: 'stateA',
                                  files: [
                                      'stateA.css',
                                      'stateA.js',
                                  ],
                              },
                          ]);
                      },
                  ],
              },
          })

          .state('stateB', {
              url: '/stateB',
              controller: 'StateBCtrl',
              templateUrl: 'stateB.html',
              resolve: {
                  load: [ '$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                          return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                              {
                                  name: 'stateB',
                                  files: [
                                      'stateB.css',
                                      'stateB.js',
                                  ],
                              },
                          ]);
                      },
                  ],
              },
          });
  });
```

I have also created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ASvmqXPLtuOREvzmWF2u) to demo a working model.

[Documentation](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs) to know more about possible config options.

Hope it helps!